# How do I split the results of an Ansible list?

Tags: ansible

I am trying to split the results of the contents of a register.  The results I get are from the grep command and it has the file I'm looking for separated by a colon(:).

The playbook is as follows:

```
    ---
    - name: "Identify locations of local interactive user home directories"
      getent:
        database: passwd
        split: ':'
      register: passwd
      tags:
        - audit
        - RHEL-07-021040-audit
        - cat2-audit
        - remediate
        - RHEL-07-021040-remediate
        - cat2-remediate
        - not-evaluated
        - not-remediated

    - name: "Search local interactive user initialization files for 'umask'"
      shell: grep -oi ^umask {{ item }}/.* -d skip| grep -v '.bash_history'
      loop: "{{ passwd.ansible_facts.getent_passwd | dict2items|json_query('[? contains(value,`/bin/bash`)].value[4]') }}"
      register: umaskfiles
      #when: passwd.ansible_facts.getent_passwd | dict2items|json_query('[? contains(value,`/bin/bash`)].value[4]')
      failed_when: umaskfiles.rc > 1
      tags:
        - audit
        - RHEL-07-021040-audit
        - cat2-audit
        - not-evaluated

    - name:
      debug:
        msg: "{{ umaskfiles.results[0] | dict2items | json_query('[? contains(key,`stdout_lines`)].value[0:]') }}"
      tags:
        - audit
        - RHEL-07-021040-audit
        - cat2-audit
        - remediate
        - RHEL-07-021040-remediate
        - cat2-remediate
        - not-evaluated
        - not-remediated `
```

```
ansible-playbook 2.9.6
  config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = [u'/etc/ansible/library']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible-2.9.6-py2.7.egg/ansible
  executable location = /usr/bin/ansible-playbook
  python version = 2.7.5 (default, Aug 13 2020, 02:51:10) [GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-39)]`
```

```
TASK [rhel-disa-stig-role-master : debug] *******************************************************************************************************
 [started TASK: rhel-disa-stig-role-master : debug on chucksl10]
ok: [chucksl10] => {
    "msg": [
        [
            "/home/testusr/.bashrc:umask"
        ]
    ]
}
```

I've gotten this far, but I need to feed the results into the this task:

```
    - name: Remove 'umask' from Identify initialization files
      replace: 
        path: "{{ item.stdout_lines }}"
        regexp: '^umask'
        replace: ''
      loop: "{{ uumaskfiles.results[0:] }}"
      loop_control:
        index_var: index
      when: item.rc == 0
      tags:
        - audit
        - RHEL-07-021040-audit
        - cat2-audit
        - remediate
        - RHEL-07-021040-remediate
        - cat2-remediate
        - not-evaluated
        - not-remediated `
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
~Urbanwarrior

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

```
---
- name: "Identify locations of local interactive user home directories"
  getent:
    database: passwd
    split: ':'
  register: passwd
  tags:
    - audit
    - RHEL-07-021040-audit
    - cat2-audit
    - remediate
    - RHEL-07-021040-remediate
    - cat2-remediate
    - not-evaluated
    - not-remediated

- name: "Search local interactive user initialization files for 'umask'"
  shell: grep -oi ^umask {{ item }}/.* -d skip| grep -v '.bash_history'
  loop: "{{ passwd.ansible_facts.getent_passwd | dict2items|json_query('[? contains(value,`/bin/bash`)].value[4]') }}"
  register: umaskfiles
  failed_when: umaskfiles.rc > 1
  tags:
   - audit
   - RHEL-07-021040-audit
   - cat2-audit
   - not-evaluated

- name: Remove 'umask' from Identify initialization files
  replace: 
    path: "{{ item.stdout_lines[0].split(':')[0] }}"
    regexp: '^umask.*'
    replace: ''
  loop: "{{ umaskfiles.results }}"
  failed_when: item.rc > 1
  when: item.stdout_lines[0] is defined
  tags:
    - audit
    - RHEL-07-021040-audit
    - cat2-audit
    - remediate
    - RHEL-07-021040-remediate
    - cat2-remediate
    - not-evaluated
    - not-remediated
```